# Drawing an arc in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I know you can draw a wedge using a Kinetic.Wedge:

```
  var compassArc = new Kinetic.Wedge({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 70,
    angleDeg: 60,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    rotationDeg: -90
  });
```

This draws a "pizza slice" with a black outline around the whole thing. I just want the "crust" of the pizza, with no straight lines coming back to the center of the circle. How can I do this?

Setting the fill to `null` removes the red but leaves the outline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about creating a custom shape fot this using arc?

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/

Please keep in mind that not to close path and not to fill strokes. if so, you will get what you want. It is a KineticJS object, so that you can drag around if you want.

Here is the working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/bighostkim/WzxxH/

```
var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext();
        var x = stage.getWidth() / 2;
        var y = stage.getHeight()/2;
        var radius = 70;
        var startAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
        var endAngle = 0 * Math.PI;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
        //context.closePath();
        canvas.stroke(this);
    },
    fill: '#00D2FF',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable:true
});
```

Comment: I agree, though the upcoming kineticjs 4.3.2 is meant to introduce the arc as a shape.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Pretty odd that this was omitted, as it seems like *less* work to implement than the wedge.

Comment: Is there any way I can change the arc (the angles specifically) after creating it?

Comment: Custom shape is the way to go for now - Elite is correct though, I have plans to add an Arc shape soon (probably v4.3.3)

Comment: `Kinetic.Path` would do equally well. At least it avoids having to fiddle around with the context directly.

Comment: To change angle after created, please refer this, http://jsfiddle.net/bighostkim/vmHRY/

Comment: @bighostkim Thanks, I had come up with something similar but your's seems to be the more correct way of doing it.

Comment: change
canvas.stroke(this);
to
context.stroke(this);

Answer (score 1):

allenhwkim answer is a bit outdated and has some problems. For example the kinetic dash array would not work. So here is a revised version:

```
var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        stroke: '#000',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        dash: [8, 4],
        drawFunc: function(context) {
            var radius = 50;
            var startAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
            var endAngle = 0 * Math.PI;
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(0, 0, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
            context.fillStrokeShape(this);
        },
        draggable:true      
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Kinetic.Arc](http://lavrton.github.io/KineticJS/api/Kinetic.Arc.html) class which you can use. 
Make outerRadius equal to innerRadius and you will get what you want.

```
this.arc = new Kinetic.Arc({
  innerRadius: 90,
  outerRadius: 90,
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  angle: 60,
  rotationDeg: 210
});
```